# R program to draw a graph i.e network diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, visnetwork, ggraph

I have a dataset of 20 movies, their genres, and their ratings. 
I want to draw a network diagram with all movies in one colour and all genres in another colour with edges going from genres to movies with the width equal to the value of ratings.

Example of dataset:

```
From (genre)  to(movie)    weight
fantasy       ironman      6.3
```

Comment: Please provide us with your data using `dput(your_df)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `igraph` to plot a bipartite graph like below

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% df$genre
E(g)$weight <- df$weight
V(g)$color <- V(g)$type
V(g)$color=gsub("FALSE","red",V(g)$color)
V(g)$color=gsub("TRUE","green",V(g)$color)
plot(g, edge.color="gray30",edge.width=E(g)$weight, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

which gives

[image]

**Dummy Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    genre = sample(paste0("g",1:5),10,replace = TRUE),
    movie = sample(paste0("m",1:10),10),
    weight = 10*runif(10)
)
```